# Can the "screenshot" functionality be removed from an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, screen, screenshot, screen-capture, printscreen

I'm creating an iPhone app for a client who's not comfortable with allowing users the ability to take a screenshot of the app content. Is there an API to block this while the app is running?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121970/notification-of-or-detecting-screenshot-being-taken

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586592/disabling-iphone-screenshot-feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible, see [this duplicate question and it's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121970/notification-of-or-detecting-screenshot-being-taken). There are a bunch of other [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586592/disabling-iphone-screenshot-feature) on SO with basically the same answer - not much you can do.

The best idea I've seen so far is to force the user to keep their finger on the touch screen to show the image (but even that is fairly easy to get around).