# is there any API to forbid user capture app screen as image?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disabling iPhone screenshot feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586592/disabling-iphone-screenshot-feature)

as topic...

how to forbid user capture app screen (press power key + how key) ?

just want protect the content of the app ....

thanks for tip