# how to disable screen capture in ipad

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disabling iPhone screenshot feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586592/disabling-iphone-screenshot-feature)

I want to make an application in which i have to either disable screen capture or replace the image taken for some security purpose.please help me if any one have any suggestion...

thanks in Advance

Comment: It seems the flood gates are open atm

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, at least not on standard iOS app (i.e. non-jailbroken). Why would you need that level of security anyway? If the user has seen a screen then they will have seen it already so what's the problem of being able to screenshot it?

Comment: or indeed them whipping out a compact camera and taking a photo....

Comment: I'm guessing secure video playback is involved.

Comment: And you're suggesting they'd be able to take screenshots enough times per second to get a decent frame rate of stolen video?