# Disable Print screen in iOS 7

Tags: ios, screenshot, ios7

Regarding this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586592/disabling-iphone-screenshot-feature), it seems that print screen ( either by <kbd>Home</kbd> + <kbd>Sleep</kbd> or via Assistive Touch menu ) cannot be prevented without using iPhone Configuration Utility.

But in this [article](http://www.todaysiphone.com/2013/07/ios-7-beta-4-adds-new-api-for-screenshot-detection-solves-snapchat-problem/), it suggests that iOS 7 ( starting from beta 4 ) has a new API to detect screenshot. I tried to look into Apple's iOS 7 documentation but it does not directly mention anything related.

Is the new API available in iOS 7 ( official version ) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling iPhone screenshot feature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586592/disabling-iphone-screenshot-feature)

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS Detection of Screenshot?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484516/ios-detection-of-screenshot)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to detect screenshot by a new method in `UIApplication` class, called `UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification`.

Notification will be posted when user presses <kbd>Home</kbd> + <kbd>Sleep</kbd> to print screen. Available in iOS 7 or above.

Reference: [UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification)

Comment: This doesn't disable print screen, but there isn't a way to disable print screen. Print screen is a system wide feature and apple doesn't like blocking those kind of features. The best you can do is just notify the user or the user on the other end that a screenshot was taken (snapchat does this). i figure you know this already shivan, i'm just stating it in addition to your content.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Therefore, this method does not help blocking the Print screen. Any workaround ?

Comment: doesn't help to disable it