# Restrict taking screenshot from iPad

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, ipad

I'm working on an iPad  application for a client, the issue is that customer's information will show up on the iPad. My client is worried that the information could be caught using the iPad screen capture feature (home + power button), then emailed or synced from the phone. Is there any way to disable the screen capture feature or can we restrict customer to take screenshot from iPad ? Can this be done programatically or is it any way to restrict them or is it possible through a configuration profile?

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586592/disabling-iphone-screenshot-feature

Comment: Here is a discussion of some options:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586592/disabling-iphone-screenshot-feature

Comment: Even if you could, what's to stop someone aiming a camera at the screen and taking the picture?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't disable that function. It is provided by OS.

What you can do is in your app, don't provide the sensitive data.

Another way is not recommended: Jailbreak the device.