# Is there a way to disable screenshot in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, screenshot

I want my Xamarin Forms application to disable screenshots. Is there a way to do so? 
Note: I found solutions in pure Android and iOS versions, but I need Xamarin solution. If there is a way to embed pure Android and iOS solution in someway, I also accept that.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There is no 100% effective** way to block user from taking screenshot/record.

You have some things you can do but none of them gives you the guarantee that the user didn't do that.

I will always need to implement this specific in Android and iOS.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9822076/how-do-i-prevent-android-taking-a-screenshot-when-my-app-goes-to-the-background) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606689/how-to-prevent-screen-capture-in-android) for android.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680028/ios-app-prevent-screen-capture) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586592/disabling-iphone-screenshot-feature) for iOs

Comment: Is there a way to apply them in Xamarin Forms?

Comment: You will have to do it specifically in Android and iOS projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable screenshots adding this line on MainActivity.cs (Xamarin):

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   ...
   ...
   Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Secure, WindowManagerFlags.Secure);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can't stop the screenshot capture. Instead of we can make the black screen for all screenshot. Add under the AppDelegate.cs

```
    public override UIWindow Window { get; set; }

public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
              Window = new UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
                var initialViewController = new SplashViewController();
                Window.RootViewController = initialViewController;
                Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
               MakeSecureWindow();
                return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
            }


public void MakeSecureWindow()
        {
            var field = new UITextField();
            field.SecureTextEntry = true;
            Window.AddSubview(field);
            field.CenterYAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(Window.CenterYAnchor).Active = true;
            field.CenterXAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(Window.CenterXAnchor).Active = true;
            Window.Layer.SuperLayer?.AddSublayer(field.Layer);
            field.Layer.Sublayers.LastOrDefault().AddSublayer(Window.Layer);
        }
```