# How to use setScreenCaptureDisabled xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, flag-secure

**Please don't mark question as duplicate.cuz FLAG_SECURE don't works for me.**
As [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31521045/11390822) someone had recommended to use **setScreenCaptureDisabled**,
But he didn't added any example and also I use xamarin.
So how do I use setScreenCaptureDisabled for disabling screen recording in xamarin ?
I need working code example for xamarin c#.

Comment: Hi, I have checked in local site refer to [this document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager), however can not make it works in Xamarin Android. It needs to apply for system administrator permissions, and from official document can not find the key about `setScreenCaptureDisabled` in [uses-policies](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver). Later if good news will update here.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Glad someone have seen and working on it. :)

Comment: `setScreenCaptureDisabled` can only be used by a device or profile owner. these are APIs designed for MDM provider, not really for applications. A device owner can only be installed on a freshly wiped device, Google has a [profile owner sample](https://github.com/android/enterprise-samples/tree/master/BasicManagedProfile)

Comment: Okay any advice or suggestion ? I just want to secure content.

Comment: @SorryIwontTell did you find any solution regarding this? i'm also struggling for the same problem it has become headache?

Comment: Nahi, main kuch khalti ker raha tha, jis waja se flag secure work nahi ker raha tha. Ap es ko use kero bhai: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54193681/11390822

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in Android. You cannot prevent screen capture on a device that is not managed through a MDM provider. There is no DRM solution available to prevent screen capture for consumer Apps. The idea is that you are supposed to provide tools and features to your users, not prevent them from doing something.

The only thing you *can* do is to set the `FLAG_SECURE` on the window to prevent it to show up when screen sharing or in screenshots.

This really has nothing to do with Xamarin, but rather, simply how Android works.

Comment: Thanks. I ticked and gave +50 bounty. Please also see my other similar questions (1)[https://stackoverflow.com/q/63617411/11390822] 
(2)[https://stackoverflow.com/q/63638950/11390822]

Comment: They are all the same question

Comment: No, 1) Detect vysor. 2) half screen screen is recordable .Please read the details. All are related but different.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable screenshots adding this line on MainActivity.cs:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   ...
   ...
   Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Secure, WindowManagerFlags.Secure);
}
```

Comment: Confirmed this works on Android 14. A toast message appears stating the app doesn't allow screen shots when attempting.