# Is it possible to stop taking screen shot from iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to stop taking screen shot of my Application Screens.
Is any one know is it possible or not.

Comment: Do you mean that you've made an app, and you don't want users to be allowed to make screenshots of it?

Comment: No this is not possible!!!

Answer (score 1):

This feature is only restricted by the OS so cannot be disable that feature in iOS.

iOS provide notification for this event: `UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification.`

**Note:** `UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification` is posted after the screenshot is taken. Currently there is no way to be notified before a screenshot is taken.

Answer (score -1):

i think it is not possible, once check following link, i hope it will help you. :)

[Disabling iPhone screenshot feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586592/disabling-iphone-screenshot-feature)

Comment: your answered link is not working, means when i open any selected answer link it's give me page not found error. so please check your answer link and update it.

Comment: @Tj3n , please check first answer iPhone Configuration Utility. this page not open... same as other answered link not open..